# CSS Absolute element on a gallery, respecting a 16:9 ratio

Tags: css, position, absolute

This is my first question, I don't think I'm doing something wrong asking it, as it's specific, I'm trying to do a gallery, this gallery has pages, each of which has a caption, I need to show an image with 16:9 ratio and the caption no matter how long it's.

As it's right now, it can show the caption, but when we resize the browser to a smaller breakpoint, if the caption is too long it will just break (will show the caption but maybe not the image if the caption is too long).

That's the solution I'm looking for right now, I'll leave a jsfiddle as an example, I tried to make it the simplest possible, so don't look at the ugly arrows and stuff :P.

fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Vb7bP/5/

An ugly fix for this would be to change the padding-bottom here:

```
.galleryContainer {
    padding-bottom: 56.25%; // This is for the image to respect a 16:9 aspect ratio.
}
```

But that won't work cause it might break if the caption is too long or too short, we might loose our 16:9 ratio.

The caption css I think is fine, it's positioned at the bottom of the div as absolute.

```
.galleryCaptionWrapper {
    background: #ccc;
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    padding: 25px;
    z-index: 3;
    bottom: 0;
}
```

Any kind of help will be much appreciated, sorry if the question is wrong. Thanks!

Comment: do you want the image to be 16:9, or the total image/caption area to be 16:9?

Comment: @BrianO'Neill I want the image to be 16:9, then comes the caption

Comment: I've also tried adding top: 56.25%; and removing the bottom:0; from the galleryCaptionWrapper class, this works for larger captions but it hides some text if the caption is too long, also, if the caption is too short it will show a part of the image under the caption.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is this what you're looking for?

http://jsfiddle.net/Vb7bP/3/

I think you had absolute positioning on a lot of things where you didn't need it.  Pertinent css is here:

```
.galleryImageWrapper {
    background-color: #000;
    width: 100%;
    padding-bottom: 56%;
    position: relative;
}
.galleryImageWrapper img {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    height: 100%;
}
```

I had a similar question myself:

[Scaling object element height proportional to width + constant with CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14161321/scaling-object-element-height-proportional-to-width-constant-with-css)

You don't have to do anything special to make the caption come after the image. That's the standard behavior for block elements.