# How to style a div to be a responsive square?

Tags: css, layout, responsive-design, aspect-ratio

I want my div to adapt its height to always equal its width. The width is percental. When the parent's width decreases, the box should decrease by keeping its aspect ratio.

How to do this is CSS?

Comment: Square elements in pure css is challenging and with limitations, but [has been answered before](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13851940/pure-css-solution-square-elements/13852277#13852277). Another useful reference may be [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14161321/scaling-object-element-height-proportional-to-width-constant-with-css/14162000#14162000).

Comment: For a responsive grid of square elements you can check this answer : [responsive square columns](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20456694/responsive-square-columns/20457076#20457076)

Comment: Perfect square on any screen: http://jsfiddle.net/far4jqt2/2/

Comment: Here's a good article with a good explanation... https://spin.atomicobject.com/2015/07/14/css-responsive-square/

Answer (score 264, accepted):

Works on almost all browsers.

You can try giving `padding-bottom` as a percentage.

```
<div style="height:0;width:20%;padding-bottom:20%;background-color:red">
<div>
Content goes here
</div>
</div>
```

The outer div is making a square and inner div contains the content. This solution worked for me many times.

Here's a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/x6jj3dar/)

Comment: It works, but I don't understand the technique. Could you please explain why this actually works?

Comment: This is very good tutorial if you want to use padding-bottom method. [link]http://www.dwuser.com/education/content/creating-responsive-tiled-layout-with-pure-css/

Comment: Preferable to the chosen answer because it works within the constraints of a container, NOT the viewport which is rarely useful

Comment: I didn't like this one at first because it looks like a hack, anyhow there's a good discussion at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11003911/why-are-margin-padding-percentages-in-css-always-calculated-against-width

Comment: Don't forget `box-sizing: content-box;` in case you add border on the entity. Else it can distort the 1:1 ratio. (happened when adding fat border-radius)

Comment: This is really, really cool. How did I not know that? You can get anything to have an aspect ratio, for example I just set my padding-bottom to be 120%, and now the width:height ratio is 1:1.2 - amazing.

Comment: does not seem to work on new ie - Edge when element has display:flex;, it actually works on older versions

Comment: It doesn't seem to work for me in Chrome somehow. If there is no content in the inner div, the box ratio is 1:1, but when I add content in the inner div, it takes some space and make the height greater than width.

Comment: @C.Lee You have to add `position: absolute;` on the inner `div` to make it work. Elements with absolute positioning are ignored when the parent dimensions are calculated. That means you can add content, but also padding, borders, etc to the inner element. :) See [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sg4q2qyc/).

Comment: This technique is actually used to display images in Google AMP. Cool!

Comment: If someone is using flex containers beware because it does not work correctly in nested structures

Answer (score 217):

To achieve what you are looking for you can use the [viewport-percentage length](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-values/#viewport-relative-lengths) `vw`.

Here is a quick example I made on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/djburkhart/Rc9fa/1/).

**HTML:**

```
<div class="square">
    <h1>This is a Square</h1>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.square {
    background: #000;
    width: 50vw;
    height: 50vw;
}
.square h1 {
    color: #fff;
}
```

I am sure there are many other ways to do this but this way seemed the best to me.

Comment: This is definitely the cleanest solution. For people interested in browser support, I found [this overview](http://caniuse.com/viewport-units).

Comment: Very nice but browser support is a little bit sketchy at the moment though isn't it - http://www.google.ie/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CEAQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fcaniuse.com%2Fviewport-units&ei=H3OfUojKDoWu7Aav64HICQ&usg=AFQjCNGClMNGOWMz16go3FPckmKbSmthnw&sig2=ra5HzgNeZxkBSVlFXY1cSA&bvm=bv.57155469,d.ZGU

Comment: This solution doesn't play nice with a grid system. If you're looking at squares expanding with columns width, the answer of @rahulbehl works better.

Comment: Browser support for `vw` : http://caniuse.com/#search=vw

Comment: Browser support is pretty solid for vw, but it probably won't work for you if your pages scroll.  vw is effectively the width of the window, not the viewport, as it includes scrollbars (same with vh for vertical stuff).  Bad decision by the spec authors in my view, because this has the potential to be a super useful unit of measurement, but if your pages scroll, you're better off using @rahulbehl's solution.  I can't think of a use case where it's handy to have the width including the scrollbars... but it is what it is.

Comment: this deform the image, and is better if you can recort it, so :/

Comment: Tip: if you want to fit a square inside a viewport on either portrait or landscape view:
```
@media (orientation:portrait){width:100vw; height:100vw;}
@media (orientation:landscape){width:100vh; height:100vh;}
```

Comment: Note: this would be bigger than the viewport on superultrawide monitors where 50vw > 100vh

Comment: Weird stuff happens if parent is `flex`.

Answer (score 72):

HTML

```
<div class='square-box'>
    <div class='square-content'>
        <h3>test</h3>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.square-box{
    position: relative;
    width: 50%;
    overflow: hidden;
    background: #4679BD;
}
.square-box:before{
    content: "";
    display: block;
    padding-top: 100%;
}
.square-content{
    position:  absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/38Tnx/1425/

Comment: This is pure magic, but it works! Thanks!

Comment: What kind of black magic is this ?!

Comment: This solution works really well when the width might be restricted by a 'max-width' rule. In those cases the actual computed width might be less than the width set in percentage and all the other solutions which set the padding directly on the outermost element will fail.

Comment: Oh man, this is saucy. 100 points to gidzior

Comment: As @daniels mention, it's important to set the padding on the pseudo element for it to correctly be constrained by `max-width`

Comment: Using ".square-box:after" instead of ".square-box:before" seems to behave in the exact same way.

Comment: This works because that the padding of an element is calculated relative to the *width* of its parent element.

Comment: I have been looking for answers to keep aspect ratio of divs while resizing them with flex box and this is the only one that worked perfectly. Pure magic, thanks!

Comment: The accepted answer does not work. This one works perfectly. Thanks !

Comment: Piling on to say this is absolute CSS magic. The only one that worked here.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer

Answer (score 35):

It is as easy as specifying a padding bottom the same size as the width in percent. So if you have a width of 50%, just use this example below

```
id or class{
    width: 50%;
    padding-bottom: 50%;
}
```

Here is a jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/kJL3u/2/

**Edited version with responsive text**: http://jsfiddle.net/kJL3u/394

Comment: This grows out of the square aspect ratio once you add content to it, though.

Comment: You can fix that problem with `overflow:hidden` or other absolute positioning of children inside the container. Conveniently exactly like @gidzior's answer

Answer (score 8):

Another way is to use a transparent 1x1.png with `width: 100%`, `height: auto` in a `div` and absolutely positioned content within it:

html:

```
<div>
    <img src="1x1px.png">
    <h1>FOO</h1>
</div>
```

css:

```
div {
    position: relative;
    width: 50%;
}

img {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}

h1 {
    position: absolute;
    top: 10px;
    left: 10px;
}
```

Fidle: http://jsfiddle.net/t529bjwc/

Comment: This is a more useful method, because you have actual size and height to work with - useful for elements inside the square div.

Comment: Nice tip, but this works even better with `<svg viewBox='0 0 1 1'></svg>`

Comment: Uhh this doesnt look right at all

Comment: This should go into the meseum of "what it used to take to make css work" lol

Answer (score 3):

This is what I came up with. Here is [a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Czkdt/).

First, I need three wrapper elements for both a square shape and centered text.

```
<div><div><div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit,
sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat
volutpat.</div></div></div>
```

This is the stylecheet. It makes use of two techniques, one for [square shapes](http://jsfiddle.net/UWERB/12/) and one for [centered text](http://www.andy-howard.com/verticalAndHorizontalAlignment/index.html#).

```
body > div {
    position:relative;
    height:0;
    width:50%; padding-bottom:50%;
}

body > div > div {
    position:absolute; top:0;
    height:100%; width:100%;
    display:table;
    border:1px solid #000;
    margin:1em;
}

body > div > div > div{
    display:table-cell;
    vertical-align:middle; text-align:center;
    padding:1em;
}
```

Comment: Extra elements for a simple square, yuk, but works I suppose. Side note; `display:table-cell` is not supported in IE7 or older.