# Diamond divs fit to container

Tags: html, css

I've this code :

```css
.container {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 30px;
}
.container div {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
  background: blue;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
</div>
```

I want these `div`s to fit whatever the `.container` width is. I want to set dynamic `width` and `height` to them.

Thanks for your help !

Answer (score 2):

CSS handles the rotation **after** painting the element, so we can't just use `width: 25%` for the diamonds, we will have to be smarter.

Using some geometry:

- The formula for the width would be `25% / sqrt(2)` (which is approx. 17.677%)
- The formula for the margins would be `(25% - (25% / sqrt(2))) / 2` (which is approx. 3.661%)

Don't use `display: inline-block` here because it adds a tiny gap of about `4px` between elements; use `float: left` instead.

Here are your diamonds! (Using [this method](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19068538/5743988) for styling the `div`s as squares)

```css
.container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 180px;
  background: gray;
}
.container div {
  width: 17.677%;
  padding-bottom: 17.677%;
  margin: 3.661%;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  background: blue;
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
</div>
```

I've added a background color so that you can see the size of the container. If you also want the height of the container to fit the diamonds, I made a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/c1k9qq7d/2) that makes a small modification.

Answer (score 0):

You should use some percentages here if you want an easy method. Also replace inline-block with a float. Worth noting if you use a float, make sure you clear the parent container to avoid and layout issues...

css:

```
.container {
  width: 100%;
}
.container div {
  width: 25%;
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
  background: blue;
  float: left;
}
.container div:before {
  content: "";
  padding-top: 100%;
  display: block;
}
```

[See Example](https://jsfiddle.net/eLv3uwth/1/)

Comment: It's working, I want them to be next to each other by the peak, because here they are over each other

Comment: @Doidgey, please use clear:both whenever you are using float as then you are not able to check them in inspect and you will get white space issue. updated  your fiddle. Check https://jsfiddle.net/LeoLion/eLv3uwth/4/