# Bootstrap Squared Columns for Tic-Tac-Toe Board?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design, grid-layout

I am building a Tic-Tac-Toe interface, currently using HTML, CSS, and Bootstrap. I'm trying to get the board to be perfectly squared (1:1) but I'm getting nowhere.

The boxes have to be taller so they use up more space. I can playing with the `height` property using `vw`/`vh` units on the columns, but they won't keep the 1:1 ratio across all resolutions.

[Tic Tac Toe](https://jsfiddle.net/segura_27/43L7tpya/)

This other version has some "pads" on each side of the board and does the job but breaks on sizes smaller than tablets. Apart from that I lose too much space.

[Tic Tac Toe with Pads](https://jsfiddle.net/segura_27/t31p2xaj/)

---

Now, here's the code for the Tic Tac Toe without pads:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Tic Tac Toe</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-/Y6pD6FV/Vv2HJnA6t+vslU6fwYXjCFtcEpHbNJ0lyAFsXTsjBbfaDjzALeQsN6M" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css">
  <script src="js/script.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-12 col-sm-2 ads"> "ads </div>
      <div class="col-12 col-sm-6 content">
        <div class="container-fluid tic-container">
          <div class="row tic-row">
            <div class="col-4 tic-box"> 1 </div>
            <div class="col-4 tic-box"> 2 </div>
            <div class="col-4 tic-box"> 3 </div>
          </div>
          <div class="row tic-row">
            <div class="col-4 tic-box"> 4 </div>
            <div class="col-4 tic-box"> 5 </div>
            <div class="col-4 tic-box"> 6 </div>
          </div>
          <div class="row tic-row">
            <div class="col-4 tic-box"> 7 </div>
            <div class="col-4 tic-box"> 8 </div>
            <div class="col-4 tic-box"> 9 </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-12 col-sm-2 tic-panel"> PANEL-THINGY<br>Score:<br>Foo bar: stuff<br> Reset game and all that blah </div>



      <div class="col-12 col-sm-2 ads"> ads </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

---

```
.ads{
  text-align: center;
  margin: .4vw 0;
  background: #F4CC70;
  padding: .4vw;
}

.content{
  margin: .4vw 0;
  background: lightblue;
  padding: .4vw;
}
.tic-panel{
  border: solid 2px black;
  margin: .4vw 0;
  background: #66A5AD;
  padding: .4vw;
}

.tic-box{
  border: solid black 1px;
  font-size: 5vw;
  background: #6AB187;
  text-align: center;
  color: lavender;
}
.tic-box:hover{
  background: #20948B;
}
```

Anyways, I would appreciate some pointers to what I'm doing wrong or what I should do. I guess I'm doing something wrong, not taking full advantage of bootstrap.

Also, I would love if you could tell me if I doing something against the principles of bootstrap, such as using `rows` or `col` where I shouldn't.

Comment: This is actually a great use-case for CSS Grids. Are you familiar with that module?

Comment: @Tyler, I'm not! Are they supposed to be used in conjunction with Bootstrap? I will take a look at it! Thank you!

Comment: CSS Grids is a vanilla CSS module that works entirely separate from Bootstrap. You can read the spec here: https://www.w3.org/TR/css-grid-1/ but it is pretty dry reading. Easier to digest places to read about it are here: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/ and here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Grid_Layout

Comment: Essentially, if you have a grid layout you want to make, CSS Grids is designed specifically for that (hence the name).

Comment: @TylerH, I'm reading the csstricks.com guide and it looks like this replaces bootstrap? Correct?

Comment: @TylerH, geez. I'm already in love with the grid! haha I'm using grid layout + media queries for the whole thing. Thank you sooo much. Bye bootstrap.

Comment: Maybe take a look [at this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19068070/how-to-style-a-div-to-be-a-responsive-square) on how to create responsive squares.

Answer (score 0):

Add the following properties to the "tic-box" class:

```css
.tic-box {
  width: 85px;
  height: 85px;
}
```

Then you will be able to delete the numbers and maintain the dimensions.